# alarm manager turning my variables into null when the alarm fire

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

calling alarm:

```
        Log.e("call: ", "calling alarm");

        sessionForPost =  Session.getActiveSession();
        if(sessionForPost != null)
            Log.e("session: ", "not null");
        else
            Log.e("session: ", "null");

        Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
        alarm.SetAlarm(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

alarm manager class:

```
public static class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver 
{    
    static String victimId = null;
    static Context context;

    public Alarm(Context context){
        Alarm.context = context;
    }
    public Alarm(){
        if(sessionForPost != null){
            Log.e("Alarm session: ", "not null");
        }
        else
            Log.e("Alarm session: ", "null");

    }


     @SuppressLint("Wakelock")
    @Override
     public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) 
     {   
         PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
         PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "my wak up lo");
         wl.acquire();

         if(sessionForPost != null)
            Log.e("onReceive session: ", "not null");
        else
            Log.e("onReceive session: ", "null");

         postFromAlarm(sessionForPost);


         Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

         wl.release();

     }

 public void SetAlarm(Context context)
 {
     if(sessionForPost != null)
            Log.e("SetAlarm session: ", "not null");
        else
            Log.e("SetAlarm session: ", "null");

     Alarm.context = context;
     Log.e("setalarm: ", "i am here");
     AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     Intent i = new Intent(contextForPost.getApplicationContext(), Alarm.class);
     PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Alarm.context, 2, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
     am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+ 1000 * 10, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
 }

 public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
 {
     Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
     PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
     AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     alarmManager.cancel(sender);
 }
}
```

postFromAlarm() method:

```
public static void postFromAlarm(Session session){
    String victimId;
    if(flag){
     Log.e("flag: ", "true");
    }else{
     Log.e("flag: ", "false");
    }
    if(Session.getActiveSession() != null)
        Log.e("session: ", "not null");
    else
        Log.e("session: ", "null");

    if(Session.getActiveSession() != null){
     Log.e("onRecieve: ", "i am here");

    Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString("message", msg);

        Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                JSONObject graphResponse = response
                                           .getGraphObject()
                                           .getInnerJSONObject();
                String postId = null;
                try {
                    postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG,
                        "JSON error "+ e.getMessage());
                }
                FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                if (error != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(contextForPost,
                         error.getErrorMessage(),
                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(contextForPost, 
                             postId,
                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                //Log.e("Ashchi to: ",error.getErrorMessage());
            }
        };
        Log.e("Ashchi to2: ","poststory class");
        if(friendId != null){
            victimId = friendId;
        }else{
            victimId = user_ID;
        }
        Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), victimId+"/feed", postParams, 
                              HttpMethod.POST, callback);

        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);

        task.execute(); 
        flag = true;
}

}
```

now the LogCat when i call SetAlarm() :

```
12-06 14:55:53.757: call: calling alarm
12-06 14:55:53.767: session: not null
12-06 14:55:53.787: Alarm session: not null
12-06 14:55:53.787: SetAlarm session: not null
12-06 14:55:53.787: setalarm: i am here
```

and then when the alarm fire LogCat give me:

```
12-06 14:56:04.437: Alarm session: null
12-06 14:56:04.457: onReceive session: null
12-06 14:56:04.457: flag: false
12-06 14:56:04.487: session: null
```

my manifest for alarm manager:

```
......
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
......
<application
.....
<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="com.timelystatusupdater.MyLoggedInFragment$Alarm"></receiver>
.....
```

as you can see, when i call the alarm and check out the `Session`, it is not null. But when the alarm fire the session is turning into null. what is the problem. remember `sessionForPost` is static global variable. **how can i prevent session to be turning null**

**N.B: my alarm class is an inner static class.
the alarm is firing after 10 second when the alarm is set**

Comment: can u pls tell how u resolved your issue the below solution not working for me it still returning me null pointer exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tactically, delete `android:process=":remote"`, and things may work better.

However, more generally, your process may be terminated in between invocations of `AlarmManager`, if your app is in the background. This is perfectly normal and usually is what the user wants. Your code needs to handle this situation. Static data members are a cache, nothing more -- anything that needs to survive a process termination needs to be stored persistently (e.g., database, file).

Comment: Thank u. it is working now. i just delete `android:process=":remote"`
@CommonsWare

Comment: @CommonsWare i just do this but after doing this my alarm manager is not starting alarm can u pls tell me whats the issue ?